# Problem when importing Excel File with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to python and was hoping someone could help me out.

I imported an excel file using pandas just to play around with.  However when I try do any additional analysis or coding on the data it is only using the header row of the excel file.

Here's one of the codes I used:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\at0789\Documents\Test File.xlsx')

data=list(df)
print(data)
```

Here's the output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/at0789/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/at0789/.spyder-py3')
['Name', 'Number', 'Color', 'Date']
```

This is what my test file looks like:

Comment: `list(df)` only returns the columns. How about `print(df)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass only the string `'C:\Users\at0789\Documents\Test File.xlsx'`
And you don't have to print the df, only call it, like that

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\at0789\Documents\Test File.xlsx')
df
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\at0789\Documents\Test File.xlsx')
```

df - data-frame

Data-frame have some many built-in function. With optimisation code  with less line of code and high performance

[One best feature is play example](https://medium.com/jbennetcodes/how-to-rewrite-your-sql-queries-in-pandas-and-more-149d341fc53e) play with data as like sql query